# Self-Study: Intergrating Font-awesome and Academicons

Tags: html, css, dreamweaver, font-awesome

I am so new to HTML and CSS. I would like to work on a free template first to see what is going on behind the template. I using [this free template](http://www.styleshout.com/free-templates/ceevee/). It uses font-awesome icons. And I know that font-awesome does not have some icons like Research-Gate and Academia et cetera... I would like to implement them by using [Academicons](http://jpswalsh.github.io/academicons/). But I could not do it!  I followed everything that has been written but it still does not show, let's say, Research-Gate icon! Could you please help me about tha? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It goes something like this in `<head>` tag.

a. Add font-awesome.css

b. add academicons.css  (Must be specified before font-awesome)

c. Keep the directory like this -

```
--CSS
  --Fonts
  --font-awesome.css
  --academicons.css
```

To use it add it in your HTML. eg;

```
<i class="fa fa-check"></i><i class="ai ai-google-scholar-square fa-3x"></i>
```

Here, first one is font-awesome and second one is academicons.

**[Demo Here](http://jsfiddle.net/kyagn39h/1/)**

**---UPDATE---**

Since you are using above specified template, which import all other css files in `default.css`

In this case you can put your academicons.css in `css/font-awsome/academicons.css` folder. Download the [academicons.zip](https://github-cloud.s3.amazonaws.com/releases/28595252/351015a2-2da3-11e5-841b-f4ac8843b669.zip?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AKIAIMWPLRQEC4XCWWPA%2F20150922%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20150922T182955Z&X-Amz-Expires=3600&X-Amz-Signature=375f62e771ee22368e4027767fca64b3b786588270897ca7ee08c3326a6b08bf&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&response-content-disposition=attachment%3B%20filename%3Dacademicons_v1.5.zip&response-content-type=application%2Foctet-stream) and extarct. Copy the fonts from fonts folder and paste it to `css/font-awesome/fonts`

Finally add `<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome/academicons.css">` in `head` tag.

Hope this help. Do comeback if any issue.

Comment: The point is that it is not working for this free template and I want to learn why. I mean in this template, I do have default.css. I am adding academicons.css before font-awesome. My index.html does not show it.

Comment: There must be any other issue.! Please post your code or add a fiddle or a current link of your website if you can.

Comment: The template's link is there above. Everything is clear! I mean if you download the file, you could see I only have one index.html and only one default.css